# Macro definition for memset function in C on Mac OS X

Tags: c

On Mac OS X in `/usr/include/secure/_string.h`, you can find the definition:

```
#define memset(dest, val, len)                  \
  ((__darwin_obsz0 (dest) != (size_t) -1)               \
   ? __builtin___memset_chk (dest, val, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest)) \
   : __inline_memset_chk (dest, val, len))

static __inline void *
__inline_memset_chk (void *__dest, int __val, size_t __len)
{
  return __builtin___memset_chk (__dest, __val, __len, __darwin_obsz0(__dest));
}
```

I dig deeper into the definition of the memset function and I got the above.

1. What's the meaning of `(__darwin_obsz0 (dest) != (size_t) -1)`?   I mean `size_t` is just a type like `int`.  `(size_t) -1`?
2. What's this `__builtin___memset_chk`? Is that a macro? How is that defined?

Answer (score 2):

Not the best of citations, but [according to this](https://github.com/ohler55/ox/issues/30) apparently `__darwin_obsz0` is a #define for this gcc builtin function that determines an object's size ([__builtin_object_size](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html)).

In this case, the code is trying to prevent buffer overruns. The memset is trying to see if it can accurately determine the pointed-to object's size, then passing that size onto the safer memset operation. Otherwise the less safe memset is used, trusting the length passed in by the user.

(Builtins or intrinsics are little functions that don't come from any particular library and are not macros. The compiler provides them to do some special magic, sometimes they are aliases for specific assembly instructions.)

Comment: I can confirm similar code on my x86-64 Linux PC. It helps prevent buffer overflows at compile time when possible according to https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Security_Features?rd=Security/Features#Compile_Time_Buffer_Checks_.28FORTIFY_SOURCE.29

Answer (score 0):

1) Typically `size_t` would be an `unsigned int`, thus `(size_t) -1` is a convenient way to get the largest `unsigned int` value. Remember the `(size_t)` here is a cast. I am not too sure of the LHS of that check.